# Selenium C# -loading text into text box works in IDE but not in Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to load an image into a browser using Selenium Webdriver & C#.
When I use the Selenium IDE it works fine, the IDE simply enters the file path into the text box and the image loads.
However when I import the same code into Visual Studio and run it via Webdriver I get an "InvalidOperationException:Element must be user-editable in order to clear it".

I have a suspicion that this is related to the instance of the browser that is being used. When I run the test via the IDE it uses an already open instance of Firefox, when I run via Webdriver it opens a new instance. Does this sound right? If so is there a work around?

If I click the textbox or the "Select" button to the right of the texbox it opens a file dialog box, but I loose control of the driver when I switch to the dialog box.

Otherwise is there a way I can load this image file?

A snippet of the code as uploaded from the IDE is below.
Thanks in advance for your help. 
Belinda

driver.FindElement(By.Id("Barcode_fileInput")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Barcode_fileInput")).SendKeys("C:\Users\Belinda\Pictures\ValidImageType.jpg");

Comment: Have you tried use double slashes? Like "C:\\Users\\..."

Comment: I am not able to enter any text into the textbox so the file path isn't relevant (yet). I'll take your comment into consideration if I get to that stage. Thanks!

Comment: WebDriver will always create a new instance.  Why is the input field not editable if you are operating in a new instance?  Are you doing something manually which could be automated?

Comment: Hi. I think the reach of the "Select" button spreads over the textbox (javascript), if I click the text box the file dialog appears. I can sneak the text into the textbox using the IDE just not Webdriver, and opening a file dialog box via Webdriver isn't supported (correct me if I am wrong!). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `driver.FindElement(By.Id("Barcode_fileInput")).SendKeys("C:\Users\Belinda\Pictures\ValidImageType.jpg");`

Don't include `driver.FindElement(By.Id("Barcode_fileInput")).Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="btn btn-success btn-file">
  <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
  Upload File
  <input type="file" multiple="" name="files[]">
</span>
```

If your html looks something like above use the selector pointing to input tag.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Name("files[]")).SendKeys("C:\Users\Belinda\Pictures\ValidImageType.jpg");
```

this should upload the file if your site does not restrict it. I am using C#